# Get remaining value from next row and append it to the existing row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sample data and I have given the input data set and desired output required.
The data will be always in sequence and the left over values from the next row should append to the main row.

Eg: seq number 4 to 8 and the left over value of 3 (for the column others) and that need to be added with seq number 3

Input Data

```
seq No  name    adress  Split_indicator Others
-------------------------------------------------
1   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 1
2   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 2
3   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 3
4   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 4
5   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 5
6   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 6
7   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 7
8   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 8
9   |Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 9
10  |Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 10
11  |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 11
12  |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 12
13  |Sample Data | Sample Data | 1 | Other test data 13
14  |Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 14
```

output format

```
seq No  name    adress  Split_indicator Others
------------------------------------------------
1   | Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 1
2   | Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 2
3   | Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 3,Other test data 4,Other test data 5,Other test data 6,Other test data 7,Other test data 8
9   | Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 9
10  | Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 10,Other test data 11,Other test data 12,Other test data 13
14  | Sample Data | Sample Data | 0 | Other test data 14
```

Sample data used

```
--drop table #temp
create table #temp (seq int, name varchar(100),adress varchar (100), Split_indicator varchar(10),Others varchar(1000))
GO

Insert into #temp values(1,'Sample Data','Sample Data',0,'Other test data 1' )
Insert into #temp values(2,'Sample Data','Sample Data',0,'Other test data 2' )
Insert into #temp values(3,'Sample Data','Sample Data',0,'Other test data 3' )
Insert into #temp values(4,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 4' )
Insert into #temp values(5,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 5' )
Insert into #temp values(6,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 6' )
Insert into #temp values(7,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 7' )
Insert into #temp values(8,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 8' )
Insert into #temp values(9,'Sample Data','Sample Data',0,'Other test data 9' )
Insert into #temp values(10,'Sample Data','Sample Data',0,'Other test data 10' )
Insert into #temp values(11,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 11' )
Insert into #temp values(12,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 12' )
Insert into #temp values(13,'Sample Data','Sample Data',1,'Other test data 13' )
Insert into #temp values(14,'Sample Data','Sample Data',0,'Other test data 14' )
GO

select * from #temp
```

Comment: have you try using [STRING_AGG ()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: String_Agg() can be only use if the sequence is identified. The first sequence is from row 3 to 8. @Squirrel

Comment: you can use `sum( ) over (order by . . )` to identify the group of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue is probably to identify the group of rows (eg 3 to 8, 10 to 13) for `string_agg()`. You can use `sum() over (order by )`  to form the `group`. As your `Split_indicator` is actually a string, `case` expression is used to evaluate it to integer value for `sum()`

You can execute the inner query to see how the `grp` works

Query:

```
select seq = min(seq), name, adress, 
       Split_indicator = min(Split_indicator),
       string_agg(Others, ',')
from
(
  select *, grp = sum(case when Split_indicator = '0' then 1 else 0 end) 
                  over(order by seq)
  from   #temp
) t
group by name, adress, grp
```